# Aspnet mvc 4 Bootstrap v3.3

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap, css3

Estoy desarollando en asp.net mvc 4 y tengo la siguiente consulta:

con este codigo:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <label>Ejemplo</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control"/>
</div>
```

Deberia de mostrar una caja de texto del tamaño de casi toda la pantalla, pero solo se muestra una parte.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A que se debe??? y como aria para mostrar en casi toda la pantalla con indica en la documentacion de bootstrap.

Comment: ¿Ese es todo el código de su vista ? no tiene más , quizá un contenedor, un elemento padre, tal y como está por si solo debería abarcar todo el ancho de la pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

intenta esto copia y pega

```
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
<label>Ejemplo</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre">
 </div>

<div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <label class="control-label">Apellido Paterno</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="Datos[apellidoPaterno]">
</div>
```

me cuentas si esta bien

Comment: nada, me sale mas pequeño y sin estilo.

Comment: <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                              <label class="control-label">Apellido Paterno</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" maxlength="60" tabindex="3" data-error="Es un campo obligatorio" name="Datos[apellidoPaterno]" required id="apellidosPaterno">
                              <div class="help-block with-errors">&nbsp;</div>
                            </div> mira lo acabo de probar y sale completo  copia y pega

Comment: Igual, a pesar de haber descargado el bootstrap y reemplazado en el que viene. y nada. Igual. tambien he verificado en el _layout y no hay nada que indique el tamaño.

Comment: ¿que version de bootstrap estas usando? ¿no te genera ningun error en la consola del navegador?  si estas usando css borra cookies

Comment: estoy usando el la version v3.3 de bootstrap.

Comment: pues raro que la mia tambien es Bootstrap v3.3.7

Comment: Si, estoy usando visual studio 2013 en ncapas.

Answer (score 0):

Según la [Doc. de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms). Los `forms` deben tener las clases `.form-group` y `.form-control`, la primera es la que te hace falta. Tu codigo refactorizado quedaria de la siguiente manera.

````
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ejemplo">Email address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="name">
  </div>
</form>
```

Si puedes pasar un poco mas de la estructura completa de tu pagina, serviría mucho mas (al menos para verificar si usas row y col además de lo que pusiste.
````